# Editing the tag wikis

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

We appear to be in the midst of discussing tags and the issues surrounding them, so it seems an apposite time to bring up the tag wikis.

Coming from MO, this is new to me (actually, MO may well have them - I don't know!), so I don't know what the procedure is.  According to the stock message, I have enough rep to edit them but there's another condition regarding being in the "top 20" on that tag.  I would consider it a reasonable "support task" to get some of these filled out a little.  So:

> First question: is there an easy way to find out which tags I fulfil the necessary conditions so that I can edit the wiki?

In the expectation that not many can edit that wiki as yet, but that there are many people who would be able to do so, I would also suggest that we use the answers to this discussion (with the exception of any answer to the question above) as preliminary wikis.  That is, we can shape "tag wikis" for the common tags in CW answers here, and then those with The Power can copy them over at their convenience.

> Second question: Compose a suitable "tag wiki" for your favourite tag.

(I realise that I shouldn't ask two questions in one place, but I'm guessing that there'll only be one answer to the first one and only the Men In Cyan will be able to answer it.)

Comment: I've already edited a couple of tag wikis, I'll post the current versions bellow

Comment: “Men in Cyan” is a term I’ve never heard …

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: not surprising as I invented it as I wrote it!

Answer (score 3):

> First question: is there an easy way to find out which tags I fulfil the necessary conditions so that I can edit the wiki?

Sort of, but not really. The easiest way is to look on the bottom of your profile, where there’s a list of all tags that you’re active in, sorted by frequency. This already gives a hint in which tags you’re active.

By clicking on any of those tags, you’ll get a list of all the contributions you’ve made to that particular tag, along with **your number of votes for a tag** (for example, here’s [mine for the tag `[packages]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:42+%5Bpackages%5D)). Unfortunately, this doesn’t include a total but you can easily sum the votes yourself.

Secondly, there’s the “tag homepage” – here, for example, for [`[packages]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/packages). By clicking on the “Stats” tab, you get some [statistics for that tab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=packages&sort=stats&pagesize=15). There you’ll see the **highest voted users for the chosen tag.**

Answer (score 1):

**Tag wiki for: macros**

Questions with the `[macros]` tag are about defining new commands and environments. Often these require low-level TeX primitives, but answers using LaTeX alternatives are also welcome and encouraged.

There is no need to add a `[tex]` or `[tex-core]` tag to a question about macros. This is implied.

Comment: These wikis read like a how-to for tagging. That’s not necessarily bad. However, it does differ from the primary usage on Stack Overflow: here, tag wikis (primarily) describe the *underlying technology*, not the tag. For example, the [tag wiki for `[c++]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%2B%2B&sort=info&pagesize=15) gives an excerpt from Wikipedia …. I see that this isn’t applicable for most TeX tags, however.

Comment: I see. So basically I had no idea how these wikis were used elsewhere and I just had a try. If you have some ideas on how to improve these tags please edit the answer!

Answer (score 1):

**Tag wiki for: mathmode**

Questions tagged with `[mathmode]` are about how to typeset the mathematical content in a document. For example how to produce specific mathematical constructs, or how to tweak the appearance of spacing and symbols in a formula.

Consider the [[equations]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=equations&sort=info&pagesize=15) tag for questions about how to include an equation in a document (e.g. about the "wrapper" environments such as `equation`, `align`, `gather`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a couple more tags, so that we can talk about issues of consistency.  First from Will Robertson:

> About [tex-core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tex-core/info)
>
> The tex-core tag refers to questions that are independent of formats and macro packages.

---

> The tex-core tag refers to questions that are independent of formats and macro packages. Such questions usually relate to low-level TeX programming, since only TeX primitives can be used.
>
> Note that even Plain TeX is a format in itself; users who wish to ask questions about creating documents in Plain TeX are advised to use the plain-tex tag.

Comment: I think when I wrote this the "excerpt text" didn't exist yet. I've shortened the "About tex-core" section.

Comment: @Will: I've fixed the text, and made it CW so that the answer can be used  for drafting.

Answer (score 0):

Second from me.  The styles of this and for [mathmode] and [tex-core] are all a little different: suggestions of what to do are welcome.

> About [bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/bibtex/info)
>
> This tag is for questions that concern Oren Patashnik's BibTeX program and its use.

---

> The bibtex tag covers (i) the BibTeX program written by Oren Patashnik, (ii) its widely used source representation of bibliography entries in *.bib files and the corresponding output representation in *.bbl files, and (iii) use of these in creating documents.
>
> BibTeX was written for use with LaTeX where it is most widely used, but support for it exists in Plain Tex and ConTeXt.